# How to quit command line window and still in ex mode?

Tags: vim

The normal mode status.
[image]

In normal mode to press `:` ,mode is changed into ex mode. 
The ex mode status.
[image]

Now to press  ,mant history command displayed in the command line window .
The ex mode status with a command line window.

[image]

How to quit  command line window and still in ex mode?
That is to say,to change from `The ex mode status with a command line window` into `The ex mode status`.
To enter `:q` ,it changed from `The ex mode status with a command line window` into `The normal mode status`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press `Ctrl-C`:

> CTRL-C
>   Continue in Command-line mode.  The command-line under the cursor is used as the command-line.  Works both in Insert and in Normal mode. ":close" also works. There is no redraw, thus the window will remain visible.

From Vim `:h command-line-window`.